# Is there an international standard with GIS symbols for power distribution objects?

Tags: cartography, symbology, standards

I'm wondering if there is a standard that points out symbols for power distribution objects, power plants etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in same business too,electrical power distribution GIS.due to several different standards for this field(american,dutch,ieee,...),seems there's no international standard to symbolize these objects but accomodate one of these or create your own.

Comment: Please, can you point me to one of these standards? IEEE or the ammerican one?

Thanks